# How do I run CasperJS in a batch file?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, casperjs

I want to automate my Javascript code so that when I execute a batch file it runs some basic tests for me.

I am new to batch files so I don't have much knowledge on them.

Batch file goal:

```
casperJS
echo seeker_create_account_1
```

Javascript code (start of it):

```
casper.start('http://my.monster.com', function() {
    this.echo('\nUser action: Navigate to my.monster.com');
});
```

When I run this I get errors like "unsafe to access frame" and "invalid parameters." I understand how to write normal batch files but implementing CasperJS into the equation is what confuses me. I also don't need any parameters to be put into the file but it is still asking for them.

And while I'm here, what I'm trying to do next is make it so this command can be looped however many times I want it to be. Not sure if this changes anything but figured it can't hurt to throw in.

Comment: CasperJS doesn't have an interactive mode. You have to pass it a script. Right now I only see the line `casperJS` which doesn't call your CasperJS script.

Comment: // , Artjom is right. Do you have a command line that currently works for starting CasperJS on a file? If so, can we see it? It's great to see someone focusing on automation for their own source code! That habit is rare and difficult to build.

Comment: // , Also, what do you mean by "I also don't need any parameters to be put into the file but it is still asking for them."? For what do you not need parameters? To which file do you refer? What or who is asking for what? It's somewhat confusing, since I think a lot of what this sentence is talking about is in your head.